# What is needed for working with Oracle from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, windows-7, 64-bit, odp.net

What is needed for working with Oracle from Visual Studio 2010?

Environment:
1 - On development pc:

Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit (4 GB ram, Dual-Core 2.6 GHz)

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit (4 GB ram, Dual-Core 2.6 GHz)
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- ODAC (from package ODTwithODAC112012.zip) (also ODAC10203x64.zip does not install on Windows 7 64)

2 - On server:

- Windows 2003
- Oracle 11g (11.2.0.1.0)
- .NET (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0) (SPs are installed)

Problem:
(Simple) If i create a console app in vs and set .NET version to 3.5 and plateform to x86, it works on development pc but not on the server. If I set plateform to x64 or Any CPU, it does not work; neither on development pc nor on the server (deployed).

I have searched and found there will be .NET 4 support for ODP.NET (64) on December. But I am not compiling to .NET 4.0! But .NET 3.5 (Wich is internally just .NET 2.0). Other tutorials and 'how to's do ignore any problems with 32-64 aspect of this hell!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the server have the ODP client software installed?

This can be 32 or 64 bit.  Compile to ANYCPU and it should not matter (if you were using 4.0 you would have to use 32bit for now since it doesn't seem to have the 64bit ready).

But since you are running ODTwithODAC112012 you are running the latest and greatest ODP (locally) so you should be set for a 32 bit run.  Just make sure it installed on the server and you should be set.  if it is installed, what errors are you receiving?

here are some forum help on the oracle site:
[Thread: Intermediate Language version of oracle.dataaccess.dll](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9183711) 
&
[How do I determine if my web server is correctly configured for ODP.Net?](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4579732)

Verify that ODP is installed (%ora_home%\11.2.0\client_1\odp.net).

Comment: Thanks; Yes, ODP.NET is installed on the server (I think it is included in 11g itself - wondows version). The threads you have mentioned gives a "The specified thread [0] was not found." on oracle site.

Comment: You can remove the last charcter from your links to make them work.

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian, I cannot say one way or another (I tend to utilize Window's web servers hitting Unix Oracle box back ends) but if you can verify that ODP is, indeed, installed that would be great, also what error are you receiving?

Comment: If I use Oracle.DataAccess and compile as x64 or AnyCPU I get [Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.] and if I use System.Data.OracleClient and compile as x64 or AnyCPU I get [Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.]

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian, do you need to run this as a 64bit application?  why don't you install ODTwithODAC112012 onto the server and run as 32 bit?  also, check the GAC (c:\windows\Assembly) for Oracle.DataAccess and see what version/proc is there

Comment: Because a 32 bit oracle would not take advantages of a 64 bit system (Oracle has 13 GB of out 16 GB memory occupied on server(s)). Before Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 I was using XP SP3 & VS 2008. After that change, everything is doomed and the only thing 64 bit from Oracle is ODAC10203x64.zip which does not run on Windows 7 x64! (Personal Rant: Our decision makers - on this one matter - think that only Oracle can handle our load! I doubt that to be true! I guess I hate Oracle more & more in time.).

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian, I guess what I was going for there was more of a 'see if 32 bit will work' than anything else.  I agree that 64 bit is superior.  Once again have you checked which version is in the GAC?  since you are not using 4.0 you ought to be safe to have ODAC10203x64 installed on the server and use ANYCPU.  I have compiled in Oracle in 32bit anyCPU and installed on out 64bit web server so it ought to work.

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian check out this link, http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2141277&tstart=0

Comment: Thank you for link. That answers my question partly. But with what I have at hand, I should go with ODAC10203x64 which can not be installed on Windows 7; that's my current problem! And I hope it will be released at December; because the previous schedule was for November :(