# ODP.net works locally but not on other computer

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I created a C# project on my computer that uses ODP.net, I imported the reference of Oracle.DataAccess. On my PC, I try to do a connection to the Database and it works normally, however, if I copy the .exe file of my application in another computer, it does not work and I receive the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Oracle.DataAccess,
>   Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'

Why doesn't C# encapsulate all the files needed in the .exe? What can I do to make this program work regardless of the executing computer?

Comment: It's how the .NET platform works. All reference are externally stored, in your `bin` folder, in the GAC...Maybe create an installer :)

Comment: And if your are using ODP.NET, prepare yourself to redistribute the same client installation which you are using in the your development. Even the minor version should be the same, it will prevent a lot of headache.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico If you ship the _managed_ ODP.NET provider there is that single DLL that you can include in your project and no additional dependencies to other libraries exist.

Comment: ODP.NET is a huge pain, as you need certain components of the Oracle Client installed. Instead, consider using Oracle's new [managed driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/).

Comment: @Uwe Keim, sincerely I have no knowledge about the managed version of ODP.NET. I will take a look. Is it in BETA? Nice blog entry: http://blog.vijay.name/2012/11/oracle-managed-odp-net/

Comment: @Uwe Keim: Thanks for the managed ODP.net suggestion, I will try that one in case I cannot make this work (now I have Visual Studio Express 2010, so to use the managed ODP.net, I need to install Visual Studio 2012 to use the package manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As of request by Vito,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495863/odp-net-works-locally-but-not-on-other-computer/24496206?noredirect=1#comment38035413_24496206) here is [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495863/odp-net-works-locally-but-not-on-other-computer/24496206?noredirect=1#comment37921502_24496206) as an answer:

I suggest to not use the "classic" ODP.NET which has dependencies on additional installed ODP components on the system, but instead use the [**purely managed** version of ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html).

For the managed ODP.NET you have a single assembly (i.e. a DLL) that you can ship with your application (e.g. in the "bin" folder if it is an ASP.NET application) and you're done.

Just to make it complete, the connection string in my cases looks something like:

```
<add 
    name="ora" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE))); User Id=MyUser; Password=MyPassword" 
    providerName="system.data.oracleclient" />
```

The managed version was really a huge improvement in terms of ease-of-use in my projects.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve my problem with this. Take in consideration that you need to have Visual Studio 2012 to be able to install packages.

Answer (score 1):

you must have installed version of the Oracle Database on each machine where you intend to install your application.

Another option is to go to Oracle and download just drivers.
[Download from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html), then you need to include them with your project, reference this dll.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376892/what-is-needed-for-working-with-oracle-from-visual-studio-2010) to a similar question I had. Mainly this problem is about `oracle.dataaccess.dll`, it's build platform (32 or 64) and presence of some of it's dependencies (like `OraOps11w.dll`). These things should be checked to see if are present and configured correctly. It would get big in deployment! Of-course if you are calling the library at machine level (not app level) from different applications, you should check if it's registered in GAC too.

Edit: In it's simplest form:

1 - You need to *have* these dlls in your app directory: `OraOps11w.dll`, `oci.dll`, `orannzsbb11.dll` and `oraociei11.dll`.

2 - You have to *add a reference* to `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.

Where can one get these?

1 - From the installation directory of you **Oracle Client** (not Server), if you already had installed the oracle client (including ODP.NET).

2 - If you have installed ODT.NET.

3 - By getting ODP.NET (preferably the zip archive, not the install package).

Comment: Better yet: Try using the _managed_ ODP.NET version. One single DLL to deploy in your application or Bin folder, no dependencies.

Comment: I think that his questions is related to references in general and not particularly to the ODP.NET. The answer should make clear how the references are externally referenced regardless of the vendor.

Comment: As I understand managed ODP.NET, still uses `OraOps11w.dll` internally and that dll should be presented too.

Comment: I get the same problem, I created a folder, and put the .exe with the four DLL's that you mentioned. I imagine that somehow we need to link those DLL's to the .exe, do we need to put the DLL's on the same path as in the original computer? Another note, ODP.net is not installed on the server that I'm trying to run the app

Comment: @Uwe Keim: I end up using the managed ODP.net version and it worked. Thanks very much for the suggestion. Please put the answer to vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are TONS of possible causes to your problem here. I would first start by copying the entire folder than contains the .EXE file, and not just the .EXE file itself. There are things in this folder that your .EXE needs in order to run. Also, I would check the dependencies on the computer that is not working with the program [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Things can go wrong if you develop on a 32-bit and try to run on a 64-bit. Things can go wrong if you develop on Windows and try running on MAC. There is a lot that can change from one computer to the next, and your code must be ready for that. Dependency walker can tell you if you aren't connecting to certain dependancies (mostly .DLL's) correctly. If you go into the release folder that contains your EXE, if there exists any .DLL files in that same directory, these .DLL's are likely needed on any computer that will try and run this program.